# How do I employ a custom COTURN Turn Server Configuration file?

Tags: docker, configuration, stun, turn, coturn

So this is where I'm at so far:

I have installed the following Coturn image from DockerHub: https://hub.docker.com/r/coturn/coturn

I have run a container from that image.

However, Docker implemented a default config file and I need to mount a custom config file with my username/password, port range and other custom variables for my Turn server.

I need a step by step handholding guide (for the complete dummy) on how to do this.

Help is MUCH appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to create an image with a custom turserver.conf (where you would setup your configurations)

```
docker run --name {your image name} -p 3478:3478/tcp -p 3478:3478/udp -p 5349:5349/tcp -p 5349:5349/udp -d --network=host -v {path to turnserver.conf on computer}:/etc/coturn/turnserver.conf coturn/coturn
```